# Unity tranform.forward is constanly changing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, transform, raycasting

So I'm working on a door opening system where I check trough a Raycast if the user has the middle of the screen focust on the doorknop. Here is the bit of my code that isn't working:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.transform.position, Camera.transform.forward, out rayHit, Distance))
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(Camera.transform.position, Camera.transform.forward, Color.blue);
        Collider col = rayHit.collider;
        if (col.tag == DoorKnopTag)
        {
            DoorIndicator.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            DoorIndicator.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
    else
        DoorIndicator.SetActive(false);
}
```

So I didn't put the code in that checks if the mouse is clicked when the player selects the doorknob but I'm sure that isn't the problem.

**The problem** is that when I check the Ray in my scene the line is flickering very hard. I debugged a bit and came the conclusion that the `Camera.transform.forward` is constantly changing even if I don't change the `Camera.tranform.position`. When I changed the direction of the `Physics.Raycast` to a constant Vector3 it didn't flicker anymore so I think that the problem is in the `transform.forward`. But I can't see how to fix it.

Comment: It will change if you rotate the camera too not just only when you change the camera's pos.

Comment: Well weirdest thing is that it works fine in scene 1 of my game but in scene 3 it goes al weird. BUT when I build the game it does the flickering in scene 1 to so... maybe it is a performance thing??

Comment: My comment was only addressing `transform.forward` changing not flickering. You may want to upload a gif or link a video for the flickering issue

Comment: Is the DoorKnob object part of the DoorIndicator which you enable/disable?

Comment: no the DiirIndicator is an Image of a hand.

Comment: Ok know it wont flicker anymore but it updates very slow and i changed nothing to it. I tested in scene 1 again and there it works fine. But in scene 3 not. The only difference between scene 1 and 3 is that scene 3 has more gameObjects. so maybe it has something to do with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using FixedUpdate() instead of Update().

For physics events you should use FixedUpdate(),
For graphical events you should use Update().

The reason of raycast flickering is caused by casting raycast from a collider most of the time. Check whether you have a collider on raycast origin point or not.

Comment: Alright I'll try that. But after some checking I came to the conclusion that it also has something to do with the performance of my game. For example I had all my lights set to realtime. And that makes it VERY SLOW. So after I changed some to mixed and baked the performace became better and the flickering dissapeared. But I'll certainly try your suggestion to make it even better